# How to handle JSON dates in underscore.js

Tags: underscore.js

How can I essentially query dates in underscore.js?  I know I can't do a "between" clause, but   see the below code as an example. My goal is to load the JSON data into a chart based on a user specified date range.

```
var testdata=[{"date": "1/8/2014", "y": 50, "z": 466, "a": 35},
                {"date": "1/9/2014", "y": 325, "z": 201, "a": 85},
                {"date": "1/10/2014", "y": 250, "z": null, "a": 40},
                {"date": "1/11/2014", "y": 125, "z": 500, "a": 60},
                {"date": "1/12/2014", "y": 50, "z": 466, "a": 35},
                {"date": "1/13/2014", "y": 325, "z": 201, "a": 85}
                ];

daterange = _.select(testdata, function(getdates){ return getdates between '1/9/2014' and '1/12/2014';});
console.log(daterange);
```

Update: I'm having some trouble getting my date callback to replace the "startDate" and "endDate" from Gruff Bunny's example.  Any suggestions?

```
var cb = function(start, end) {
                    $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
                    alert("Callback has fired: [" + start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + " to " + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + "]");

                    var testdata=[
                        {"date": "1/2/2014", "y": 250, "z": null, "a": 40},
                        {"date": "1/3/2014", "y": 125, "z": 500, "a": 60},
                        {"date": "1/4/2014", "y": 50, "z": 466, "a": 35},
                        {"date": "1/5/2014", "y": 325, "z": 201, "a": 85},
                        {"date": "1/6/2014", "y": 250, "z": null, "a": 40},
                        {"date": "1/7/2014", "y": 125, "z": 500, "a": 60},
                        {"date": "1/8/2014", "y": 50, "z": 466, "a": 35},
                        {"date": "1/9/2014", "y": 325, "z": 201, "a": 85},
                        {"date": "1/10/2014", "y": 250, "z": null, "a": 40},
                        {"date": "1/11/2014", "y": 125, "z": 500, "a": 60},
                        {"date": "1/12/2014", "y": 50, "z": 466, "a": 35}
                        ];

                    _.each(testdata, function(data){
                    var dateParts = data.date.split('/')
                    data.date = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[0] - 1, dateParts[1])
                    });

                    var startDate = new Date(2014,0,9) ;
                    var endDate = new Date(2014,0,12) ;

                    var requiredData = _.filter(testdata, function(data){
                        return data.date >= startDate && data.date <= endDate;
                    });
```

Comment: That's a lousy way to represent a date if you're hoping to do relative comparisons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those dates aren't easy to work with so first convert them all to javascript dates:

```
_.each(testdata, function(data){
    var dateParts = data.date.split('/')
    data.date = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[0] - 1, dateParts[1])
});
```

and then extract the data you want using _.filter:

```
var startDate = new Date(2014,0,9) ;
var endDate = new Date(2014,0,12) ;

var requiredData = _.filter(testdata, function(data){
    return data.date >= startDate && data.date <= endDate;
});
```

Comment: Thanks -- would you recommend that I just begin with JavaScript dates from my JSON file? Also -- I'm using Bootstrap Datepicker and I'm not sure how to exactly integrate that with JavaScript formatted dates (see edit in original post).

Answer (score 1):

Would recommend the excellent library momentjs

http://momentjs.com/

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

```
console.log(moment("1/8/2014").format());
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider using a library like [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) for date related stuff.

A bit unrelated, but still relevant: I created a a screencast about massaging date based data with underscorejs for binding to a rickshaw chart, check it out if you want: http://tagtree.tv/d3-with-rickshaw-and-angular